# PyCharm Version control: Disable ability to commit

Tags: svn, pycharm

In my organization we have a specific commit procedure that is to be followed prior to every commit. We are using `Subversion`. I'm trying to setup version control through PyCharm so that I have the ability to diff against committed versions, update, revert, etc. However, I don't want the ability to accidentally commit through `PyCharm` because this would go against company policy.

Is there a way to enable version control in PyCharm, but disable the ability to commit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you need [commit-hooks](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.reposhooks.pre-commit.html), which can automatically check the changes, so they would be aligned with the company's standards.
Moreover, this let anyone to benefit, even if someone is not using PyCharm (a lot of people prefer different editors).

But to implement those automatic checks you have to write some scripts and ask your Subversion administrator to install them to the server. But it absolutely worth the time and effort, as you can be sure that the code in your repository is linted, checked and aligned with company standards.

Here are some examples of the commit hooks:

- [Making the Most of Commit Hooks with Subversion](http://www.linux-mag.com/id/7151/)
- [An Introduction to Subversion Hook Scripts on Windows](http://blogs.wandisco.com/2011/11/10/an-introduction-to-subversion-hook-scripts-on-windows/)
- [SVN pre-commit hook which can syntax check all files](https://stuporglue.org/svn-pre-commit-hook-which-can-syntax-check-all-files/)